# Excel loop for data

Tags: excel, loops, formula

Let's assume this is my table

```
kit component
aa  a
aa  b
aa  c
aa  d
aa  e
ab  b
ab  f
ab  e
ab  l
```

What I am trying to achieve is some kind of formula that allows me to query the whole table and pull every single component for that particular kit so it would look like this;

```
kit    
aa

Component    
a
b    
c    
d    
e
```

Comment: Will the list always be sorted on 'kit' like the example?

Comment: What is your end goal? Try to front run the possibility of an XY question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is always sorted on kit then the following formula will work:

```
=IF(ROW(1:1)>COUNTIF(A:A,$D$2),"",INDEX(B:B,MATCH($D$2,A:A,0)+ROW(1:1)-1))
```

Copy it down as far as desired.

[image]

If your data is not sorted you will need to use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$10,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$10)/($A$1:$A$10=$D$2),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Aggregate is an array type formula and therefore full column reference should be avoided.  If you data set is large this formula will slow down the calculations times.

It is better to use the first and sort the data, but if not possible the second will work.

Comment: But a note: this can be accomplished with Advanced Filter without formulas.

Comment: Hello Scott, your 2nd formula works, however using the table you have kindly provided above i'll try and explain the issue. Instead of only listing all the components for kit "aa" it actually misses the first component of kit "aa" and bring the first component of kit "ab" so in the end the componets listed for kit aa is as follows; b,c,d,e,b - can i fix this?

Comment: Paste the actual formula you are using.

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX('MO Component List'!$C$2:$C$4807,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW('MO Component List'!$B$2:$B$4807)/('MO Component List'!$B$2:$B$4807=$K$3),ROW(1:1))),"")

Comment: @PedroBernardo you have moved the references down a row, If you look at my formula I started in Row 1 not row 2.  Either start everything in row 1 like my formula which will not matter as the Title row will not = K3 Or you will need to adjust for it: ``=IFERROR(INDEX('MO Component List'!$C$2:$C$4807,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW('MO Component List'!$B$2:$B$4807)-ROW('MO Component List'!$B$2)+1)/('MO Component List'!$B$2:$B$4807=$K$3),ROW(1:1))),"")`